# Express JS + Multer query database before file upload

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, multer

I'm using Node.JS + Express.JS + Multer to handle file uploads. The problem is that I need to query the database to see if a file with this name has been uploaded in the past. If it hasn't been uploaded, then it should be accepted. Otherwise, the file should not be accepted. I'm trying to get this to work using the onFileUploadStart function; however, the database query is asynchronous and I see no way to return false given that the result of the query appears in a callback. If there is a way to execute the query synchronously, my goal will be easy to accomplish. Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  //connection details
});

router.post('/upload', multer({
  onFileUploadStart: function(file, req, res) {
    var queryString = "SELECT count(fileName) as count FROM table WHERE fileName = ?;",
      queryInserts = [file.originalname];

    queryString = mysql.format(queryString, queryInserts);

    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        // handle error
      } else {
        if (rows[0].count > 0) {
          // file should not be accepted
        } else {
          // file should be accepted
        }
      }
    });
  },
  dest: "./uploads/"
}), function(req, res) {
  // do other stuff
});
```

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My quick reaction would be to use promises. You could have your `onFileUploadStart` handler create a deferred, assign its promise to the active request object and handle the resolution or rejection of the promise. Then in the main handler for the upload route, you could use then.

I believe this would basically be the new code as applied to your current code. I Note that I am using the [Q promises library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), but there are other options (promises are also built into ES6 if you are using it).

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Q = requires('q');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  //connection details
});

router.post('/upload', multer({
  onFileUploadStart: function(file, req, res) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    req.fileUploadPromise = deferred.promise;
    var queryString = "SELECT count(fileName) as count FROM table WHERE fileName = ?;",
      queryInserts = [file.originalname];

    queryString = mysql.format(queryString, queryInserts);

    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        // handle error
        deferred.reject('You had an error...');
      } else {
        if (rows[0].count > 0) {
          // file should not be accepted
          deferred.reject('You had a duplicate file');
        } else {
          deferred.resolve(file); // ?? or something useful
          // file should be accepted
        }
      }
    });
  },
  dest: "./uploads/"
}), function(req, res) {

  req.fileUploadPromise
  .then(function(successResult){
       // do other stuff         
     res.status(200).send('success');
  })
  .catch(function(errorResult){
     // read the error result to provide correct code & error message for user
  })
 .done();
});
```